# 2 domains, htaccess redirect one to index.html but not the other

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working on a site that has 2 domains pointing to the same public_html folder.

The server server index.html by default. My code uses htaccess to route all calls to index.php but I only want this to happen for the development URL for now and not the live URL.

I tried routing live.com and www.live.com to www.live/index.html - but I get a redirect loop as I don't know how to make it break if index.html is in the URL.

Can anyone help?

I tried:

```
# Disable live domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^live.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.live.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.live.com/index.html [L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Disable live domain
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?live\.com$
RewriteCond $1 !^index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.live.com/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Hey, cheers for that. It still gives a loop though... Even when I try RewriteCond $1 !^/index\.html too...

Comment: Try adding a rewritebase like above.

Comment: Ah, it was html bootstrap standard htaccess overrides that broke your suggestion. It works now! Thanks for your help, really appreciated!